# resolveLocalFileSystemURI error code 5 windows phone 7 phonegap

Tags: file, cordova, windows-phone-7, camera, uri

I've tried implement this work around
1.**capture a photo** 
2.**Get the photo from it's saved place** 
3.**Read photo as base64**

I've followed this methodology:

```
var cameraOptions = {};
function capturePhoto() {
    console.log("capture photo");
    cameraOptions = { quality: 70, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, saveToPhotoAlbum: true };
    doIt();
}
function doIt() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess, onCameraFail, cameraOptions);
}
function onCameraSuccess(imageURI) {
    console.log("Camera Success");

    $('#MokhalfaPhotoLocation').val(imageURI);
    console.log("Image URI: " + imageURI);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, onResolveImageSuccess, onFail); //get the file from the physical path...
}
  function onResolveImageSuccess(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, onFail);
}
function gotFile(file) {
    readDataUrl(file);
}
function readDataUrl(file) {
    console.log("read file as dataUrl");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        window.localStorage.setItem("mokhalfaPhotoURL", evt.target.result);
 };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

this chain is worked fine till the CameraSuccess then it fail on the line

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, onResolveImageSuccess, onFail);
```

it entered the onFail event With error code = 5

btw, this code worked fine on Android but the issue is here with Windows Phone 7
any one knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I recently came across this error. The solution is quite simple :)

```
function onCameraSuccess(imageURI) {
    console.log("Camera Success");

    $('#MokhalfaPhotoLocation').val(imageURI);
    console.log("Image URI: " + imageURI);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("//" + imageURI, onResolveImageSuccess, onFail); //get the file from the physical path...
}
```

If you alert the imageURI it should look like (/CachedImagePath/etcetc/), so the window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI doesnt know where to resolve so by prepending to the URI // it looks in the correct path.

Cheers, I will post this issue to their bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.  See "https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2736".  However, on my Windows 8 Phone I am not able to get to the photo file to display in an HTML IMG tag.  I've tried the fileEntry.fullPath, fileEntry.toURL() and fileEntry.toNativeURL().

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this

```
$window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file://" + videoURI, function (fileEntry) {
   console.log('Success: '+fileEntry.name);
   fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata) {
      if(metadata.size>20971520){
          $ionicPopup.alert({
              template: '<h5>Lo sentimos <i class="icon ion-sad-outline"></i> , el video sobre pasa el limite de peso</h5>',
              title: 'Limite de peso',
          });
       }else{

       }
    });
}, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
});
```